# Creating a Program for a function generator

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

so i just bought a function generator and i want to connect the ports from my program. The folder of the driver came with a program in vb6, so that makes me dont need to create the full program.

Even if im not a pro in visual basic, i translated almost everything into vb.net, but when i run the program it gives me the following error when runs `Writefile`:

```
System.AccessViolationException
```

i have searched in lot of websites and forums and tried almost everything but i dont know how to fix it. when every data arrives to "writefile" is like this:

```
WriteFile(hComm, bytebuf_t(0), wLen, gLen, 0&)
```

- `hcomm`: a large number, always something like 42221250801565695
- `bytebuf_t(0)`: 115
- `wlen`: 14
- `glen`: 0
- `0&`: (i dont really get this).

also, the writefile command is this.

```
Public Declare Function WriteFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hCommDev As Long, lpBuffer As Byte,
        ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long, lpOverlapped As Long) As Long
```

i also tried to use `system.io.filestream` but didn't work either

Comment: The use of the `Long` data type is suspect in the `WriteFile` function.  A VB6 `Long` is a 32 bit integer where-as the .Net `Long` is a 64 bit integer.  Try changing `Long` to `Integer` or `System.Int32`. In the  constant `0&` the ampersand in known as the [type character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters) for the `Long` type; it tells the compiler that you want to pass a long zero value. Just pass a `0` to the function.

Comment: I just noticed that `WriteFile` in a Kernel32 function.  See [WriteFile](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WriteFile.html) for the proper .Net signature.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, as you said the problem was the data type, once i changed it the program ran perfectly. Thank you very much!